# WebAPI Logging would not log controller activities until appsettings.json is deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

in .net 6 webAPI, when I have appsettings.json containing this:

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

It would not log the controller activities regardless which endpoint is being hit. This is the only log that is showing:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5237
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Temp\TestApps\Test1\SampleCCLogProviderApp\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\
```

But, when I delete the appsettings.json, now it shows all the informative logs:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5237
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Temp\TestApps\Test1\SampleCCLogProviderApp\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5237/weatherforecast - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'WebApplication5.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApplication5)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "WeatherForecast"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication5.WeatherForecast] Get() on controller WebApplication5.Controllers.WeatherForecastController (WebApplication5).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'WebApplication5.WeatherForecast[]'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action WebApplication5.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApplication5) in 64.1691ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'WebApplication5.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApplication5)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5237/weatherforecast - - - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 192.2900ms
```

I don't understand. Why would the existence of appsettings.json cause the WebAPI to not log the controller activities?

Answer (score 2):

You have added configuration(part LogLevel) in the Appsetting or appsettings.Development(this is for development environment) , which does not display the information log

By deleting Appsetting , those settings are no longer there
If you use the default configuration, remove this Line or change the log type and it will be fixed

```
, "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
```

OR Change log type

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information"
```

[configure-logging-using-appsettings-json-in-net-applications](https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/05/13/configure-logging-using-appsettings-json-in-net-applications/)

Comment: I actually do not have this line: , "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning" or "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information". But even if I added that line, it still would not show the controller activity

Comment: Can you show appsettings.develment.json

Comment: ah I see now! There is appsettings.development.json file sitting hidden under appsettings.json, not visible until I expanded appsettings.json. And yes it does contain the default "Warning" value for "Microsoft.AspNetCore". Thank you for pointing this out!